# Router blocking access to various CDNs

Tags: router

I bought a new router - a Netgear N300 WNR3500Lv2, because old one was giving me poor coverage. The coverage's great, but this one doesn't let me into some sites, like superuser.com, for one.

I've noticed a pattern, that all the sites my router's having trouble with are content distribution sites (superuser.com loads css and js from there), such as imgur, and cdn.sstatic.net. Accessing these sites directly in chrome gives me a cryptic `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error.

All computers connected to the internet via the router are effected. Those that are not, namely my home server, can access these sites without any problems.

- I tried changing MTU to lower values. The MTU for my connection should be 1472.
- I tried resetting the router, flipping random stuff that made any kind of sense and even flashing it to the latest firmware.

What now? RMA?

**EDIT**

I've noticed that only windows machines were effected.

Comment: Where did you change your MTU? On your router, or your clients or both? For best results, at least for the purpose of troubleshooting, try setting it to 1473 on both your router and your clients at the same time. Does that make a difference? Can `curl` or `wget` load those same files that Chrome chokes on?

Comment: @Spiff yes, I'll try that; but I'm somehow not hopeful. Meanwhile, to answer your question - I can ping cdn.sstatic.net (it resolves to sstatic.stackexchange.netdna-cdn.com and an ip), but I can not connect to port 80, with any tools.

Comment: @Spiff setting MTU on the client had no apparent effect on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've noticed that my mac was not effected by the same issue, i tried [TCPOptimizer](http://www.speedguide.net/files/TCPOptimizer.exe) tool, where I switched settings to **optimized**. After a reboot everything seems to work fine.